# dc.js - d3.js LineChart under CompositeChart hide axis indexer

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, dc.js

I have a composite chart made up by 3 line charts(two threshold and a value line)

I would like to hide the "indexer" striped lines on the two threshold charts as shown in the pictures, but I cannot found out why.

[image: la pulenta]

I don't have any particular restriction so i can accept very different solutions, even dealing with D3

UPDATE:

```
<path class="yRef" stroke-dasharray="5,5" d="M0 177L825.0110013690593 177" style="display: none;"></path>
<path class="xRef invisible-stroke" stroke-dasharray="5,5" d="M825.0110013690593 315L825.0110013690593 177" style="display: none;">
```

Those two guys in the code box are two typical references or "indexers" as i called them that are displayed when **mouse** enters on the dots

```
          /*! dc 1.7.0 .....*/      
            dots.enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("class", DOT_CIRCLE_CLASS)
                .attr("r", _dotRadius)
                .attr("fill", _chart.getColor)
                .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
                .style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6)
                .on("mousemove", function (d) {
                    var dot = d3.select(this);
                    showDot(dot);
                    showRefLines(dot, g);
                })
                .on("mouseout", function (d) {
                    var dot = d3.select(this);
                    hideDot(dot);
                    hideRefLines(g);
                })
                .append("title").text(_chart.title());
[...] });
```

Comment: can you share the code you are working on ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no option to turn off the reference lines, but you can effectively disable them by adding another style sheet with a rule like this:

```
.dc-chart g.dc-tooltip path.yRef {
    stroke: none;
}

.dc-chart g.dc-tooltip path.xRef {
    stroke: none;
}
```

Comment: But i don't want to turn them off on the main chart(the blue one). Each sub chart of the composite chart has a name given by the DC library so it's with a autoIncrement variable, so they can be distinguished but this solutions is rather not flexible. I will try to scavenge a bit more inside the libraries in order to understand how to "peacefully interfere" with its behaviour

Answer (score 0):

There's a option "renderlet" in dc.js and "selectAll" in d3. Now I used this option to fix this problem. Add this code during mouseout event on ".dot"

```
d3.selectAll("#line-chart .dc-tooltip path").attr('d','');
```

This code remove the dashed line from line chart

```
lineChart.on('renderlet', function(chart) {
                        d3.selectAll("#line-chart .dot").call(tip);
                        d3.selectAll("#line-chart .dot")
                            .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                            .on('click', tip.hide)
                            .on('mouseout', function(d) {
                                tip.hide();
                                // dc.renderAll();
                                d3.selectAll("#line-chart .dc-tooltip path").attr('d','');
                            });
                    });
```

Full Code is given below

**Html Code**

```
<div id="line-chart"></div>
<div id="log">Incoming Data:</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var startDate = new Date("2011-11-14T16:17:54Z");
    var currDate = moment(startDate);
    var cf = crossfilter([{date: startDate, quantity: 1}]);
    AddData();
    AddData();

    var timeDimension = cf.dimension(function(d){ return d.date; });
    var totalGroup = timeDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d){ return d.quantity; });

    var lineChart = dc.lineChart("#line-chart")
        .brushOn(false)
        .width(800)
        .height(200)
        .renderDataPoints(true)
        .elasticY(true)
        .x(d3.time.scale().domain([startDate, currDate]))
        .dimension(timeDimension)
        .group(totalGroup);

    dc.renderAll();



    function AddData(){
        var q = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        currDate = currDate.add('month', 1);
        cf.add( [{date: currDate.clone().toDate(), quantity: q}]);  
        $("#log").append(q + ", ");
    }


    //set custom html tooltip
    var tip = d3.tip()
                .attr('class', 'tip')
                .offset([-10, 0])
                .html(function(d) {

                            return d.data.key + " <br> Quantity : " + d.data.value;
                    });

    lineChart.on('renderlet', function(chart) {
                        d3.selectAll("#line-chart .dot").call(tip);
                        d3.selectAll("#line-chart .dot")
                            .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                            .on('click', tip.hide)
                            .on('mouseout', function(d) {
                                tip.hide();
                                // dc.renderAll();
                                d3.selectAll("#line-chart .dc-tooltip path").attr('d','');
                            });
                    });
    dc.renderAll();
```

During mouseout event striped lines will be hidden. on mouseover will visible  the striped lines automatically. :)